# ¿Cómo puedo cargar un script desde mi servidor php y ejecutarlo?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, script

Al inicio de mi página quiero mostrar un aviso de cookies si este no se ha aceptado aún. En caso de que no, entonces hago una petición **ajax** y obtengo el html, y esto es lo que recibo como respuesta:

```
<div>
    <img class="cookie shake-hard_two" src="statics/img/svg/icons/cookie/cookie_kookie.png" />
    
    <div class="cookie secundario_1">
        <h1 class="cookie">USO DE COOKIES</h1>
        
        <p class="cookie">Usamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar nuestros servicios.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="cookie secundario_2">
        <div class="cookie secundario_2_1 shake-horizontal_one">
            <input type="button" value="Mas info." id="button_cookie_1">
        </div>
        
        <div class="cookie secundario_2_2 shake-horizontal_one">
            <input type="button" value="Ajustes" id="button_cookie_2" onclick="javascript: clickCookieAjustes()">
        </div>
        
        <div class="cookie secundario_2_3 shake-horizontal_one">
            <input type="button" value="Aceptar" id="button_cookie_3" onclick="javascript: clickCookieAjustes()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function clickCookieAceptar() {
        alert("esta es la alerta de aceptar");
    }
    
    function clickCookieAjustes() {
        
    }
</script>
```

Pero al dar clic en el botón `Aceptar` me sale error de que la función `clickCookieAceptar()` no existe.

La petición la recibí como texto y la agregué a traves de la manipulación del DOM `document.getElementById("elemento").innerHTML`.

Pude recurrir a un archivo de estilo y este hizo efecto de forma satisfactoria.

Me gustaría saber de qué forma puedo agregar un nuevo script después de que la página ha terminado de cargar.

Comment: Si bien es posible lo que pides, mediante diversas técnicas para hacerlo, no le veo sentido a que lo hagas así.  Deja ya incluido el javascript de las funciones de las cookies en la carga inicial y te ahorrarás este problema.  Aparte, en tu ejemplo no llamas a esa función, seguramente lo has editado antes y por error lo has pegado mal aqui.

Comment: El método `innerHTML` no hace parse de tags `script`, por lo cual, aunque recibas la definición de la función en la respuesta ajax, la misma no será analizada. Todo esto es por seguridad. La recomendación que te hacen es que tengas ya definida la función al momento de la carga de la página, aunque se haya aceptado o no el aviso de políticas de cookies. Saludos